# How do I check checkboxes on a page using IWebDriver in selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to select multiple checkbox to Submit the form and the following code response in HTML format.
Here i have 4 check box. when i have launch the browser then first 3 checkbox is always checked and last one always Unchecked. Now i want first 3 checkbox should be uncheck and last one will be checked .how do i this with selenium c#

```
                                        <div class="formSubSection">
                                            <h4>
                                                Details:</h4>
                                            <div class="formField">
                                                <div class="formFieldCheckBox">
                                                    <span title="Imported selector"><input id="aul00_ContentPlaceHolder1_aul02_chkVan" type="checkbox" name=aul00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$chkVan" checked="checked"><label for="aul00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_chkVan"> Is the Helpdesk?</label></span>
                                                    
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="formField">
                                                <div class="formFieldCheckBox">
                                                    <span title="home selector"><input id="aul00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_chkHome" type="checkbox" name="aul00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$chkHome" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_aul02_chkMotorHome"> home?</label></span>
                                                    
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="formField">
                                                <div class="formFieldCheckBox">
                                                    <span title="Imported selector"><input id="aul00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_chkHorseBox" type="checkbox" name="aul00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aul02$chkHorseBox" checked="checked"><label for="aul00_ContentPlaceHolder1_aul02_chkHorseBox"> Is the vehicle?</label></span>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                           <div class="formField">
                                                <div class="formFieldCheckBox">
                                                    <span title="car selector"><input id="aul00_ContentPlaceHolder1_aul02_chkCar" type="checkbox" name="aul00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$chkCar" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_aul02_chkCar"> Is the Driver?</label></span>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends are you web elements have dynamical id and names.

I wold suggest solution to get all 4 elements (according to your post, I do not know rest of the DOM) and just to iterate trought the for loop. Something like

```
for(int i=0;i<driver.findElements(By.Class("formFieldCheckBox"));i++)
{
    if(i>=5)
    {
        if(!driver.findElements(By.Class("formFieldCheckBox")).get(i).isSelected())
           driver.findElements(By.Class("formFieldCheckBox")).get(i).click();
    }
    else
    {
       if(driver.findElements(By.Class("formFieldCheckBox")).get(i).isSelected())
           driver.findElements(By.Class("formFieldCheckBox")).get(i).click();
    }

}
```

This is the Java solution, but almost same code is for C#. Try it and let me know did it help.

Comment: Thanks for update ..but here i am not able to use isSelected method ..i have searched in google so we can use selected method we half of this .but this method also not working for me . in DOM 9 check box is displaying .first 6 checkbox should be uncheck and remaining 3 should be checked

Comment: Use  bValue = oRadioButton.ElementAt(0).Selected; that is how to do it in C#. And for first 6 that should be checked and otjhers not I edited the question.